# retrieve elements by a superset of their field with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My mongoose schema for `Recipe` looks like this:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const RecipeSchema = new Schema({
  recipeName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please add a recipeName"],
    maxlength: [99, "max 50 chars are allowed for the recipeName"],
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },

  ingredients: [
    {
      quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
      ingredient: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "Ingredient",
      },
    },
  ],

  description: [
    {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please add a description"],
      maxlength: [5000, "max 50 chars are allowed for the description"],
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Recipe", RecipeSchema);
```

Given a list of ingredients' ids, I want to be able to find all the recipes whose ingredients list is a subset of the list I am searching by.

I tried a couple of things to no avail, like for instance given

```js
  const ingredients = [
    ObjectId('614af0b845d87d639b1d337a'),
    ObjectId('614b12bebfbe29d357515c63'),
  ]
```

trying to retrieve by

```js
Recipe.find({ ingredients: {$not: { $elemMatch: { $nin: ingredients } } }})
```

This doesn't work because I am not taking into account the right field `ingredient`, but I do not know where that should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `ingredients` is an array with ingredients ids, which needs to be a superset of the ingredients array in the recipe, this query works:

```js
   Recipe.find({ ingredients: { $not: { $elemMatch: { ingredient: { $nin: ingredients } } } } })
```